# libarchive how to read concatenated tar

Tags: c++, libarchive

I want to read a tar file that was made by concatenating multiple `.tar.gz` files using `cat one.tar.gz two.tar.gz .... > combined.tar.gz` using libarchive.

I'm able to read files for the first tar file fine using a `while(;;)` `r = archive_read_next_header(a, &entry);`, but as soon as finishes reading it, I get a `Closing file Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

How do I let libarchive move to reading the next tar file?

Comment: Ok, I'm currious. `cat one.tar.gz two.tar.gz .... > combined.tar.gz` - *Why* would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the library supports this. Only need to set the `read_concatenated_archives` option set.

`archive_read_set_options(a, "read_concatenated_archives")`

see [here](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/blob/3649ed23c6b4392d692580c03b10a611e3eaaa32/libarchive/test/test_read_format_tar_concatenated.c) for an example.